# How to Set Eclipse Workspace to Current Directory in Windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, portability

I am using Eclipse in a flash disk. I also copy my Eclipse projects in the same flash disk. I need to set my workspace as this flash disk.

My problem is, if I set my workspace to `F:\workspace` (currently the letter is `F`), when I use my flash disk on another computer, it may be not `F:` but `E:`.

Is there a global string in Windows that I can write to set the workspace as current directory?

Similar to `./workspace` in Linux.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  You might actually have better luck asking this on the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) Stack Exchange site.  SO is more for questions directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `../workspace` on windows, and I would assume `./workspace` will also work. I see no problem with just `workspace` however...

Comment: That's OK but when I import a project, its path is F:\workspace

Comment: @cagirici I don't know then... When I use Windows, I use eclipse on a flash drive but I have never tried importing a project.

Answer (score 0):

No, but when you start Eclipse you can hit "Browse" and go to the directory you want to save the workspace in.  The workspace is that directory until the next time you reset it.

Answer (score 0):

i use ./workspace as the space. 
like below
this is eclipse positon
D:\IDE\eclipse\e3.6.2\eclipse.exe
i will put workspace at this
D:\IDE\eclipse\e3.6.2\workspace

when you start eclipse you can use  ./workspace as the workspace postion